# Flex : Unable to extend DataGridColumn

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am unable to compile the following Flex application.
All I am trying to do is, to extend DataGridColumn class.
I get the following compile error :

**Could not resolve  to a component implementation.

    DataGridColumnTest/src  DataGridColumnTest.mxml line 6**

DataGridColumnTest.mxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local='*'>
    <mx:DataGrid x="191" y="32">
        <mx:columns>
            <local:ExtendedDataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="col1">
                 <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Button label="test"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
           </local:ExtendedDataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

ExtendedDataGridColumn.mxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:DataGridColumn xmlns="*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"> 
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `<local:itemRenderer>` instead of `<mx:itemRenderer>` since itemRenderer is a property of ExtendedDataGridColumn which has the namespace prefix local. The namespace prefix of properties has to match the component's prefix.

So, the correct code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local='*'>
    <mx:DataGrid x="191" y="32">
        <mx:columns>
            <local:ExtendedDataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="col1">
                 <local:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Button label="test"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </local:itemRenderer>
           </local:ExtendedDataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```